# Is it possible to change the Double column Decimal Size

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao, alter

Is it possible to change the Double column Decimal Size(Number of Decimals) in MS ACCESS using C# with the help of DAO/Query.

> As per the MSDN
>
> size :    The field size in characters (Text and Binary fields only).

[Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/alter-table-statement-HA001231431.aspx)

Size can be used within the ALTER query for Text and Binary fields only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, DAO can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DAO_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // required COM reference: Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
            var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database db = dbe.Workspaces[0].OpenDatabase(@"C:\__tmp\testData.accdb");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Field fld = db.TableDefs["poiData"].Fields["lon"];
            Console.WriteLine("Properties[\"DecimalPlaces\"].Value was: " + fld.Properties["DecimalPlaces"].Value);
            fld.Properties["DecimalPlaces"].Value = 5;
            Console.WriteLine("Properties[\"DecimalPlaces\"].Value is now: " + fld.Properties["DecimalPlaces"].Value);
            db.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit a key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question: I am using Access 97, My columns are of Type DOUBLE with "Decimal Places" = 2. Without changing the "Decimal Places" = 5 its taking 5 decimal places when i inserted the data. Is there any problem in my database or by default its like that only?

Comment: @andy AFAIK for `Single` and `Double` fields the `DecimalPlaces` property is really more of a display hint than anything else. I just tried in Access 2010 and I can add a `Double` with 6 decimal places into a field where `DecimalPlaces` is set to 4.

Comment: What u suggest whether i have to change the Decimal Places or i have to go without changing?

Comment: @andy That really depends on what the fields represent and what you want to do with them. Fields imported from Excel are often cast as `Double` in Access, but if those numbers represent currency amounts then the `Currency` type in Access is a better choice. If it's just the number of decimal places *displayed* that is of concern then set the `Format` of the field to `Fixed` and the `DecimalPlaces` value to the number of decimal places you want.